# angularjs, ng-model and maxlength: String was not truncated

Tags: angularjs, maxlength, ng-maxlength

If I have this html:

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="person.name" maxlength="10" />
```

And this js (angularjs)

```
   $scope.person = {
       name: "Larger than 10"
   };
```

What I get, "rendered", is this:

[image: maxlength]

But I was expecting that maxlength would truncate the string, as it does when you are typing from scratch (when the input field starts in blank). Check this gif animation:

[image: maxlength doesnt let the user to continue typing]

**Question**: Is there an easy workaround to get what I was expecting?

The problem is that I can't get the model value if it is not a valid length, ie:
Send later `$scope.person.name` through an ajax request

Note: ng-maxlength behaves the same

Comment: When using `ng-maxlength` it should set the `maxlength` error key. You can check that key in your template code and display an error when your model is initially loaded in and then prevent the user from submitting the form (or whatever) until the model validation passes.

Comment: Can you use ng-change and only return the first characters of the string?

Comment: Why would want such an ANTI-user behaviour? if you truncate, you should notify. You are leaving the user with something that he didn't want. same goes for all types of breaking the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can create yours own directive

```
app.directive("limitTo", [function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var limit = parseInt(attrs.limitTo);
            angular.element(elem).on("keypress", function(e) {
                if (this.value.length == limit) e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    }
}]);

<input limit-to="4" class="" ng-model="person.name" placeholder="">
```